# Acumatica GI customization - adding total lines column

Tags: acumatica

While creating GI for sales order screen I want to display the total number of lines in document details tab. Can anyone suggest a way to start implementing this?

After including the custom field in GI it doesn't populate the column with data.

The code for printing the row count is as below which is also discussed in [Adding custom button in acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45740204/4405230)

```
public void SOOrder_UsrTotalTransactions_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
  {
      e.ReturnValue = GetTotalTransactions(sender);
  }

  // Update values
  public void SOLine_RowDeleted(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
  {
      UpdateTotals(sender, e.Row as SOOrder,  true);
  }

  public void SOLine_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
  {
      UpdateTotals(sender, e.Row as SOOrder,  true);
}

  public void SOLine_OrderQty_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
      UpdateTotals(sender, e.Row as SOOrder, false);
  }

  public void UpdateTotals(PXCache sender, SOOrder soOrder, bool isUpdateTranCount)
  {
      // Get SOOrder DAC extension
      if (soOrder != null)
      {
          SOOrderExt soOrderExt = sender.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(soOrder);

          if (soOrderExt != null)
          {             
               if (isUpdateTranCount)
               {

                   sender.SetValueExt<SOOrderExt.usrTotalTransactions>(soOrder, GetTotalTransactions(sender));

               } 
          }
      }
  }



  public int? GetTotalTransactions(PXCache sender)
  {
      return Base.Transactions.Select().Count();
  }
 }
}
```

the DAC code is:
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Total Lines", Enabled = false)]

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is the GI just uses the DACs and if you are setting an unbound field in another graph or within the dac referencing another graph it will not work in the GI which is its own graph. Maybe the use of some type of PXProjection or PXDBCalc field. Alternative would be to simply store the value into the field and save to the DB in the sale order graph.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I store the value in the database?

The custom i created does show the value but it doesn't saves in the DB...it shows NULL

Comment: you need to find the right trigger... maybe persist override would be easiest and before calling base persist check the row count (watch out for deleting still being included in the count) and update your order UsrRowCount value.

Comment: can you include the code you have to help answer the question? - include it in the question - not a comment if you can please

Comment: I have edited my question with the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to set the value I would try a simplified version of your example like this...

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public void SOLine_RowDeleted(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTotals(sender, e.Row as SOOrder);
        }

        public void SOLine_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTotals(sender, e.Row as SOOrder);
        }

        public void UpdateTotals(PXCache sender, SOOrder soOrder)
        {
            if (soOrder != null)
            {
                SOOrderExt soOrderExt = sender.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(soOrder);

                if (soOrderExt != null)
                {
                    sender.SetValueExt<SOOrderExt.usrRowCount>(soOrder, GetRowCount());
                }
            }
        }

        public int GetRowCount()
        {
            return Base.Transactions?.Select().Count() ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use FieldSelecting to set unbound field values. Because your field is bound you do not want to call fieldselecting for your example.

Comment: you are welcome Glad i could help. I am guessing you just needed to remove fieldselecting and to set your value using sender.SetValueExt which is the better way to set values in events. More so when you want the related field events to fire at that point in time vs waiting until the end of the calling event.

Comment: i am getting this error after modifying it according to the above code...
error CS0118: 'PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderExt.UsrRowCount' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

The error is for this line >>sender.SetValueExt<SOOrderExt.usrRowCount>(soOrder, GetRowCount());

Comment: can you include your dac declaration in the question? the type on set value should be lowercase usRowCount abstract class version of the field but the error is pointing out the Uppercase UsrRowCount which is the property.

Comment: Oh okay...so I changed it to usrRowCount and the error has gone...but now it doesn't shows the total number of rows...the value isn't displayed

I have updated the code in the question

Comment: debug the results returned from GetRowCount. You can also try to fix in a value to setvalueex to make sure everything is wired up. I also see you are adding a total qty field. Just as an FYI there is already a total qty field in case you are trying to implement your own.

Comment: and you confirmed the SetValue was setting the correct row value? (debugging you could see the correct row count?) If you add a new line and save you should see your field update. Can you include your DAC/field code in your question to make sure the field is setup correctly.

Comment: Yes..the SetValue is setting the correct row value and even on adding a new row the field is getting updated.

But it isn't storing the value in the database. If I create another field and enter row count manually then it stores in the database...

Comment: sounds like the field is not setup correctly; Try and use the new field